# CreateSymbolicLink runs on Windows 8 returns error code 1314 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, wix

I am trying to create a symbolic link from a custom action dll using Wix installer.

The custom action is run as an administrator and I confirmed it by using code from:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppUACSelfElevation-5bfc52dd

The problem is that on Windows 8 the symbolic link is created, however on Windows 7 error `1314` is returned:

> ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD1314 (0x522)
>   A required privilege is not held by the client.

Both Windows 7 and Windows 8 users are capable of running the process as administrators.

Any idea how I can solve this issue please?

Regards,
Noel

Comment: The msiexec service process doesn't have all available rights, whether you're admin or not. It explicitly removes rights that MS believes you don't need during an install. Hence the message. You can't enable that privilege because it doesn't even exist in the process to be enabled. The list of rights of the msiexec service tends to change from release to release, which is why the difference. Can't find a list, though I've seen them in the past. That means you can't do anything from a custom action, so I recommend doing it as a standalone process when your app first runs.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/10/30/preview-of-upcoming-kb-articles-windows-installer-4-0-on-windows-vista.aspx (scroll down a bit to privs list) and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2514642 relating to SeBackUpPrivilege which you cannot fix with adjusting privileges because the privilege isn't even in the process to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out is that with an MSI installer on Windows 7 or Vista Windows will not let you create a Symbolic link even if the installer is run as an administrator. What I ended up doing is by wrapping the .msi installer into an .exe using InnoSetup and ran the symbolic link commands from the executable.

On windows 8 this works because the Installer version has changed.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't telling you you don't have access rights, it's telling you you don't have *privilege*.  Certain privileges need to be requested explicitly under certain versions of the OS.  Windows 7 seemed to to have SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege off even with administrator access.

Pseudo code, but I believe you have to adjust privileges for your process token before calling `CreateSymbolicLink`

```
LUID luid;
if(LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, _T("SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege"), &luid))
{
    HANDLE hToken = get_process_token();
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES token_privileges;
    token_privileges.PrivilegeCount             = 1;
    token_privileges.Privileges[0].Luid         = luid;
    token_privileges.Privileges[0].Attributes   = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    if(!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &token_privileges, 0, NULL, NULL))
    {
        // TODO: call GetLastError and report an error.
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, there's only one privilege that is enabled by default, SeChangeNotifyPrivilege.  However, some API functions automatically enable the privilege(s) they need if they are available.  It's also possible that the installer's token has been explicitly stripped of this privilege as per PhilDW's comment, though that would seem odd to me.

Comment: It's not odd - it's standard MS practice that services have the least privilege that they need. The other privileges are explicitly stripped because otherwise why bother if a CA Dll call can just restore them?

Comment: I thought we were talking about an installer here--it has to have admin access once running.  Plus, the privilege in question seems to *only* be off by default on Win 7.  the opposite of "standard"

Comment: No, it's least privilege still, rather it's the set of privileges that MS thinks an install needs. As illustrated by http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2514642 they sometimes go too far.

Comment: level of privileges is different from whether or not it's running elevated.  We've clearly established that the installer does *not* have all privileges.  It's still running elevated, otherwise there would be little an installer could actually do.